# Image form field Sencha Touch 2

Tags: image, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create a *Sencha Touch 2* form panel for a model in which one of the fields contains the *URL* to an image file.  If I include a textfield, it'll display the text of the *URL* correctly, but what I really want is **to display the image found at that URL**, and I'm not sure how to do that.  If I use `xtype: image`, I think I need a `src config`, and I'm not sure how to specify that the desired value is in one of the form fields.  My view looks like this:

```
Ext.define("CatalogApp.view.ItemDetailView", {
   extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
   requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
   alias: "widget.itemdetailview",
   config:{
      scrollable:'vertical'
   },
   initialize: function ()
   {

      this.callParent(arguments);

      var backButton = {
         xtype: "button",
         ui: "back",
         text: "Home",
         handler: this.onBackButtonTap,
         scope: this
      };

      var topToolbar = {
         xtype: "toolbar",
         docked: "top",
         title: "Item Detail",
         items: [
            backButton
         ]
      };

      var mainLayout = {
         xtype: "container",
         layout: 'hbox',
         items: [
            {
               xtype: 'textfield',
               width: 200,
               name: 'thumbUrl'
            },
            {
               xtype: "fieldset",
               flex: 1,
               items : [
                  {
                     xtype: 'textfield',
                     name: 'itemNbr',
                     label: 'Item Nbr',
                     disabled: true
                  },
                  {
                     xtype: 'textfield',
                     name: 'itemDesc',
                     label: 'Item Desc',
                     disabled: true
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      };

      this.add([
         topToolbar,
         mainLayout
      ]);
   },

   onBackButtonTap: function ()
   {
      console.log("backToHomeCommand");
      this.fireEvent("backToHomeCommand", this);
   }

});
```

How can I set up this view to display the image correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define new Sencha component: ImageField

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.field.ImageField', {
extend: 'Ext.field.Field',
requires: [
    'Ext.Img'
],
xtype: 'imagefield',
config: {
    component: {
        xtype: 'image'
    }
},

updateValue: function(value, oldValue) {
    var me = this,
        component = me.getComponent();

    component.setSrc(value);
},

proxyConfig: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
}

});
```

Than in form:

```
Ext.define("CatalogApp.view.ItemDetailView", {
extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
alias: "widget.itemdetailview",
config:{
  scrollable:'vertical'
},
initialize: function ()
{

  this.callParent(arguments);

  var backButton = {
     xtype: "button",
     ui: "back",
     text: "Home",
     handler: this.onBackButtonTap,
     scope: this
  };

  var topToolbar = {
     xtype: "toolbar",
     docked: "top",
     title: "Item Detail",
     items: [
        backButton
     ]
  };

  var mainLayout = {
     xtype: "container",
     layout: 'hbox',
     items: [
        {
           xtype: 'imagefield',  // only this change
           width: 200,         
           height: 150,
           name: 'thumbUrl'
        },
        {
           xtype: "fieldset",
           flex: 1,
           items : [
              {
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'itemNbr',
                 label: 'Item Nbr',
                 disabled: true
              },
              {
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'itemDesc',
                 label: 'Item Desc',
                 disabled: true
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  };

  this.add([
     topToolbar,
     mainLayout
  ]);
},

onBackButtonTap: function ()
{
   console.log("backToHomeCommand");
   this.fireEvent("backToHomeCommand", this);
}

});
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Thanks Oleg, that seems to do the trick very nicely.  I have a followup question, though: would there be an easy way to enhance this custom field so that the image is rendered as a hyperlink to a document whose URL is in another field on the form?

Comment: My dear, it is another question. Mark this question as answered, file new question and I will show you how to do one :)